# Two-column output format for a writing to .txt file

Tags: fortran

This is my code:

```
Program Output_manipulation

Implicit none

Integer::i, j, k, i_index_1, i_index_2
Integer,parameter:: Br_sn_cvo=3, Br_nn_cv=2, Br_nn_mre=2, Le=350
Character(Le),parameter:: fmtB_1_1 = "(*(2x,i3,'.',2x,f5.2,1x,'j',1x,f5.2))"
Complex,parameter:: S_pot=cmplx((2.3,3.4))

Open(Unit=15,File='Output.txt',Status='Unknown')

Do k = 1, Br_nn_mre

   i_index_1= Br_sn_cvo + Br_nn_mre + 1 + Br_nn_cv*(k-1)
   i_index_2= Br_sn_cvo + Br_nn_mre + 1 + k*Br_nn_cv-1

   Write(15,fmtB_1_1)i_index_1,S_pot,i_index_2,S_pot

End Do

Close(Unit=15,Status='Keep')

End Program Output_manipulation
```

The content of `Output.txt` is:

```
  6.   2.30 j  3.40   7.   2.30 j  3.40
  8.   2.30 j  3.40   9.   2.30 j  3.40
```

I have a intention to get this content in `Outpur.txt`:

```
  6.   2.30 j  3.40   8.   2.30 j  3.40
  7.   2.30 j  3.40   9.   2.30 j  3.40
```

I do not have a idea how to create format for this kind of writing in .txt file.
Is there some way for doing that with implied do loop?
I want from code to write column afther column.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old-school version with implied do-loop

```
    Program Output_manipulation

    Implicit none

    Integer::i,j

    Open(Unit=15,File='Output.txt',Status='Unknown')

    Do j=1,3

          Write(15,'(3(2x,i0,2x,"Thing_",i0))') (i+j,i,i=1,3)

    End Do

    Close(Unit=15,Status='Keep')

    End Program Output_manipulation
```

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet, only a single do-loop is used. The loop index `irow` ranges from `0:nrows-1`, where `nrows` is any positive integer and so can be adjusted without changing the algorithm. The initial left-hand column label `min` can be calculated from any variables/parameters you want, e.g. `min=a+b`. You can also extend the technique shown here to write more than two columns using the same logic, but you will still only need one do-loop.

```
!! ... types used in this snippet:
implicit none
integer :: a, b, nrows, min, irow, idx_column1, idx_colum2
complex :: spot = complx(2.3,3.4)
character(len=48) :: form

!! ... other code, assignments, etc.

form  = "(*(2x,i3,'.',2x,f5.2,1x,'j',1x,f5.2))"
min   = a + b

do irow = 0, nrows-1
    idx_column1 = min + irow
    idx_column2 = min + nrows + irow
    write(*, form)  idx_column1, spot, idx_column2, spot
enddo
```

Example output, with `nrows=3`:

```
12.   2.30 j  3.40   15.   2.30 j  3.40
13.   2.30 j  3.40   16.   2.30 j  3.40
14.   2.30 j  3.40   17.   2.30 j  3.40
```

If the thing you're actually printing to each line is an array of variables, you can index into it using some combination of `min, nrows, irow, idx_column1, idx_column2`.

---

Style suggestions:

1. Please, use whitespace between your variables like you do between words when you write a sentence. For legibility, and all that.
2. Try to be more succinct in your loop indexing. For example, `i=Br_sn_cvo+Br_nn_mre+1+Br_nn_cv*(k-1),Br_sn_cvo+Br_nn_mre+1+k*Br_nn_cv-1` is really hard to read, or (for me) to care to read. Do it at least for us poor souls on StackOverflow.

Notes:

1. You don't need to `trim(adjustl("My Fun Format"))`. Try it, you'll see.

Comment: @judge_dred That's because you are still using `advance=no`. You may need to look at how I set the loop index as well, it's not clear you understood that part.

Comment: @Judge_Dred You're still doing the indexing wrong. Do the math on your indexing. As you've written it, in the first loop index_1=3+2+1=6 (ok), but index_2=3+2+1+2-1=7 (no, bad, try again). However, as you can see from my example output, when you use the indexing scheme I've shown, it does actually print the way you want it to.

Comment: What is bad with math in indexing? Just use any math. Te problem with writing is same.

Comment: @Judge_Dred Do what I showed you, then profit and learn. Last post.